# How to call a file from another folder?

Tags: node.js

I have Two folders, one is Src and another one is Test. Both having each JS file. I have assigned a call function in a file of source folder. I want to call a file from test folder. Now I have doubt, how to define a path to call the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open file in another folder with node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697138/open-file-in-another-folder-with-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right, you have two files, in spearate folders, and you'd like to `require` a `.js` file from another folder.

This is a way how you can achieve this:

```
// src/example.js
require('../test/example_test.js');
```

---

```
// test/example_test.js
module.exports = {
    method(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a function called "helloJS " in a file named "hello_js.js" as shown below:

```
helloJS = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
    response.send("Hello from JS codebase!");
});
```

you can call it like this:

```
require('./events/hello_js.js');
module.exports = {
    helloJS
}
```